# why selectedrowstyle of a gridview is not shown when doing asyncpostback?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview, updatepanel

I have a gridview which contains a select commandfield.

I also have an updatepanel which contains a details view.

The gridview is outside update panel.

I want when selected button is pressed the selected row of the gridview to change color and the details to be shown in the details view without page refreshing.

Here is my code:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Column1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField HeaderText="details" ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Column1" HeaderText="Column1" SortExpression="Column1" />
        </Columns>
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </asp:GridView>


    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="Column1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"  Height="50px" Width="125px">
                <Fields>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Column1" HeaderText="Column1" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Column1" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Column2" HeaderText="Column2" SortExpression="Column2" />
                </Fields>
            </asp:DetailsView>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The problem is that gridview does not change the color of the selected row when it is outside the update panel.
I know that when i move it inside the updatepanel it will work but I want to know why this happens.

Thanks.

Forgot the most important thing:

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server"  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Products WHERE (Column1=@Column1)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Column1" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                </SelectParameters>
      </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I think this is where the source of misbehavior lies...but still i am not sure why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes my bad, I just replicated your scenario and the reason I found is really simple actually.

First, Asynchronous postbacks using the `UpdatePanel` **will only refresh its child controls** (that's why they are called partial render posts). Controls outside the `UpdatePanel` won't be refreshed.

As you mention:

> I know that when i move it inside the updatepanel it will work but I want to know why this happens.

At first sight I thought that the `GridView` should do a full postback but nope, that's because you added this control as a trigger for the `UpdatePanel`

The reason is that you are registering all the events from the `GridView` as triggers of the `UpdatePanel`, and you are registering it using this `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" />` which is causing the desired effect, firing the `GridView` events asynchronously to refresh the `UpdatePanel`, and since the `GridView` is *outside*, it is not refreshed

You could change this behavior, fixing the problem but your page will do a **full postback**:

```
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" />
```

As a reminder (for you and for me =p), we need to remember than whenever we register a control as a trigger of an `UpdatePanel`, its events will be *caught* in order to be sent asynchronously, causing sometimes the undesired effect of not rendering the source control if it's outside of the `UpdatePanel`

Comment: its not that like I said it works ok when i just transfer the gridview inside the update panel.

Comment: You were totally right, I replicated your problem and fixed, check my updated answer